# pyobjus nameerror: name 'build_ext' is not defined during installation

Tags: python, cython, autoclass

I'm trying to install pyobjus but I still geting error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /root/anaconda3/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lm35sz6r/pyobjus/setup.py'"'"'; _file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-lm35sz6r/pyobjus/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file_);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, _file_, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-lm35sz6r/pyobjus/pip-egg-info
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-lm35sz6r/pyobjus/
Complete output (5 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-lm35sz6r/pyobjus/setup.py", line 58, in <module>
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
NameError: name 'build_ext' is not defined
```

I tried many things to solve that like installing pyobjus and cython from different sources but nothing works.
Is there any other way to solve that?
Or any alternatives for autoclass function from pyobjus?
Many thanks.

Comment: Any chance you are not on macOS? Because this library seems to support only macOS. Other than that it makes more sense to open a github issue than asking here...

Comment: Yes yes. Linux here. Good point.  I will try that. Thanks