# installing python module on linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, linux-mint

I am trying to install the python module pyobjus (this is the one that fails to install another module).

But I always get some bug during installation. I tried to switch to other python versions, reinstall pip, use option --no-cache-dir, etc, but couldn't manage to get past this bug:

```
 $ pip3 install pyobjus
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pyobjus
  Using cached pyobjus-1.2.0.tar.gz (165 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 /home/denis/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpoff64vmf
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-4k26drr5/pyobjus
  Complete output (19 lines):
  Pyobjus platform is linux
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
      main()
    File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "/home/denis/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 114, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-35d2l6hi/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 150, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-35d2l6hi/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 130, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-35d2l6hi/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 254, in run_setup
      self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-env-35d2l6hi/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 145, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 35, in <module>
      class PyObjusBuildExt(build_ext, object):
  NameError: name 'build_ext' is not defined
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /home/denis/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpoff64vmf Check the logs for full command output.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
My OS is Linux Mint 19.3.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63345540/pyobjus-nameerror-name-build-ext-is-not-defined-during-installation) which is about the same problem, but following the links did not bring any answer. It says PyObjus is designed for MacOS, but then why does the module [katrain](https://github.com/sanderland/katrain), supposedly compatible with linux, tries to install it when running "pip3 install katrain" (giving the same error as above) ?

**Edit adter Marat's suggestion:**
I removed the test for ios, the installation goes a bit further, but fails because Python.h is missing. when trying to install python3-dev, apt-get says that broken packages such as python3.6-dev are flagged "left as is", so it cannot install the required ones. Is there a way to fix the python installation, which seems to be broken ? I am afraid to break all the system if I mess up with it too much, but there is clearly a problem with my installation...

Fixed the above issue by reinstalling stuff, now it is CoreFoundation.h that is missing...

Comment: it is a new bug in pyobjus 1.2. Try installing an older oversion `pip3 install pyobjus==1.1.0`

Comment: @Marat it gives the same error

Comment: then there is no easy workaround. You still  can download package archive, unpack, fix `setup.py` in line 23 to disable check for Mac OS, and install from a local source

Comment: I downloaded the project and looked at its `setup.py`. That code will only work properly on a Mac because it specifically checks `sys.platform` for "darwin" and "ios". There is an out, it will try to install if you've set the environment variable `KIVYIOSROOT`. Otherwise, `setup.py` will crash with this error instead of exiting nicely with an error message. You may want to contact the developers to see what is up with a linux install. https://pypi.org/project/pyobjus/.

Comment: @Marat - that's a good solution. I'd try adding `dev_platform = 'ios'` right before the check so that the installer attempts to build `pyobjus.c`.

Comment: @Marat thanks, it went a little further, but apparently there are deeper problem with my python installation. See the edit in the question. Do you know how I could fix it ?

Comment: `katrain` doesn't install `pyobjus` on Linux. This is the list of dependencies from `pip install katrain` in a new empty virtual env: *Installing collected packages: cython, chardet, idna, urllib3, certifi, requests, pillow, docutils, pygments, Kivy-Garden, kivy, kivymd, screeninfo, katrain
Successfully installed Kivy-Garden-0.1.4 certifi-2020.11.8 chardet-3.0.4 cython-0.29.14 docutils-0.16 idna-2.10 katrain-1.5.0 kivy-2.0.0rc2 kivymd-0.104.1 pillow-8.0.1 pygments-2.7.2 requests-2.25.0 screeninfo-0.6.6 urllib3-1.26.2*

Comment: @phd when doing pip install katrain, an error is raised by PyObjus, the same as when doing pip install pyobjus

Comment: Actually "pip install katrain --no-deps" worked, so weird ! thanks a lot !